# How to open file by using windowpopup

Tags: php, mysql

I have file (feeColect.php) which display information by using php, now I want to run (stockreportPDF.php) file after click Export PDF button, its real confuse me that what is wrong with the code while I used the same on previous project

1: this is (feeColect.php) file.

```
    <tr><td><?php echo $list->idnumber; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->class; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->boarding_fee; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->school_fee; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->trans_fee; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $balance; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->term; ?></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $list->id;  ?>">
 <?php $url_PDFstock ="stockreportPDF.php?from_date=$from_date&to_date=$to_date "; ?>
```

this is button that it suppose to open windowpop after click

```
   <?php echo "<p> <a onclick=\"return windowpop('". $url_PDFstock ."')\">
  <input class='btn btn-round btn-orange' type='button' value='Export PDF'></a></p>";?>
```

Comment: phew.. this is some weired way of achieving that.... can you point out what you originally want to achieve? This looks like an XY Problem to me. (although we do not have the complete code of receipt_print.php) And where is `$courseObj` class coming from?

Comment: $courseObj is OBJECT of the class